# Finding position of view that is inside collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, collectionview

I have tried to find view position inside collectionViewCell relative to ViewController using
 `let cellFrame = cell.convert(cell.frame, to: self.view)`

but it calculates wrong because I have section insets and collectionView offset on top. I have tried manually adding all offsets but it still hasn't gave me correct position. If I set it correctly for one device it doesn't show nicely on others. This is my layout.

[image: View inside collectionView cell]

Comment: Have you tried using `cell.contentView` rather than `cell.view`?

Comment: I have, it doesn't find right cooordinates